# Differential equation with Fresnel integral

Tags: differential-equations, integration, special-functions

We have $\frac{y'(x)}{\cos(x)}=C(x)$ and need to find y(x). Generally we should express $y(x)$ through $C(x)$ and elementary functions. I can only do it through $C(x)$ and $S(x)$, or through $\Phi(x)$. This is my solution: 
$$
y(x)=\int \cos(x)C(x)dx=\sin(x)C(x)-\int \sin(x)\cos(x^2)\,dx=\sin(x)C(x)-\int (\frac{\sin(x^2+x)}{2}-\frac{\sin(x^2-x)}{2})\,dx=\sin(x)C(x)-\int(\frac{\sin((x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4})}{2}-\frac{\sin((x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4})}{2})\,dx,
$$

$$
x+\frac{1}{2}=a,x-\frac{1}{2}=b \Longrightarrow y(x)=\sin(x)C(x)-\int \frac{\sin(a^2-\frac{1}{4})}{2}\,da+\int \frac{\sin(b^2-\frac{1}{4})}{2} \, db = \sin(x)C(x) -\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{4})}{2}(S(a)-S(b))+\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{4})}{2}(C(a)-C(b)) = \sin(x)C(x)-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{4})}{2}(S(x+\frac{1}{2})-S(x-\frac{1}{2}))+\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{4})}{2}(C(x+\frac{1}{2})-C(x-\frac{1}{2})).
$$ 
Is there any way to improve the result of this solution and express $y(x)$ only through $C(x)$?

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the layout slightly. The answer to the question is "no". $S(x)$ appears naturally in the computation and is not expressible in terms of $C(x)$ in any elementary way, as far as I know. Also, why two special functions in the answer are any worse than one?